# CompletableFuture in SpringBoot controller not working when method return type is void

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I found the following issue trying to return a photo in a SpringBoot controller (Both methods have the same behavior but the second one return the CompletableFuture).

Method 1: Does not send anything to the outputStream and the response is an http 200.

```
@RequestMapping(value = FIND_PHOTO, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
    public void getPhoto(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable String id) {
        ExceptionalConsumer<String, IOException> photoConsumer = photo -> {
            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(photo));
            response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
            StreamUtils.copy(bais, response.getOutputStream());
        };

        photoService.findPhoto(id) //This returns a CompletableFuture<String>
            .thenAccept(photoConsumer);
    }
```

Method 2: Return the data through the outputStream.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = FIND_PHOTO, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
    public CompletableFuture<Void> getPhoto(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable String id) {
        ExceptionalConsumer<String, IOException> photoConsumer = photo -> {
            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(photo));
            response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
            StreamUtils.copy(bais, response.getOutputStream());
        };

        return photoService.findPhoto(id)
            .thenAccept(photoConsumer);
    }
```

I think spring has a kind of queue for CompletableFutures waiting to finish but if the return of the method is `void`, then spring is not aware of the async behaviour and then I'll need to call `get()` or `join()` by myself.

Could someone confirm if that is the real behaviour or if there is an error from my side?

Comment: What data method 2 returns with void completablefuture? And first method retrun type is void?

Comment: @Deadpool the data is returned in StreamUtils.copy(bais, response.getOutputStream()); but that is not called if the return type is void.

Comment: You always need to return something on the `endpoint method` if you wish, else returning a `void method` never will return something. what do you expect? I think you are confusing `async programming` as `Javascript` does or another programming  language that use async..

Comment: @JonathanJohx did you see the `StreamUtils.copy(bais, response.getOutputStream());` part? It sends info even when the return is void, so no Javascript mistake. Pls, understand the question and read the code before giving an unuseful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not really call get() on a CompletableFuture if you are not handling exceptions for that....

Spring does not have that queue. That is how it is supposed to work if you return nothing than you have to call join() and the returned object from the method will be T as of CompleatableFuture or you can just return the completable future, so your observations are correct.

Comment: Thx @mrossini  Then my question will be: if I´m going to return a CompletableFuture in a controller when and how spring call the get()?

Comment: public void getPhoto(@Suspended AsyncResponse response, HttpServletResponse response....   return response.resume(compleatableFuture.join())